# how to add space or fix alignment of images

Tags: html, css, mustache

I have a Image above, the 4 images below should have space between them. I am using col-md-12 and used col-md-3 for each image. The issue is, the last image is going to the left instead of right. Images can be more than 4 that's why I need something like dynamic style to fix the alignment.

```
<div class="col-md-12  hidden-xs hidden-sm gallery_view_carmat_div">
    {{#scopes.images}}
        <div class="col-md-3 rm-padding">
            <div class="image_thumb gallery_view_carmat" data-image="{{imageMedPath}}" data-drawback-image="{{imagePath}}" data-href="{{productGalleryId}}">
              <img src="{{imageThumbPath}}" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.setAttribute('src', '{{imagePath}}');" class="gallery_view_carmat" />
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/scopes.images}}
</div>
```

width of image is 95%

result:
[image: result:]

expected:
[image: expected:]

Comment: Use `display: flex;` on the container, to equally align a set amount of content-images (or any other block container) within the flex-box. You can read up on it in-depth here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something akin to this:

```
text-align: justify;
-moz-text-align-last: center;
text-align-last: center;
```

I'm... having difficulty telling if you want them to be centred or not, but I imagine you could just change centre on the text-aligns to be right.

I know they're not text, they're images, but [last I checked](http://prntscr.com/czvfya), images are counted as part of text >>